# Why do not I get an error even when I have commented the header and used its function?

Tags: c, gcc, ctype

In the following program I commented the statement `#include <ctype.h>` in the hope that an error will be thrown while using the functions like `isupper` and `isgraph`. But to my surprise no error is thrown. Why is this so ? The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_character_classification) page lists these functions in the header type `ctype.h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
char ch;
for(;;) {
   ch = getc(stdin);
   if( ch == '.') break;
   int g = isgraph(ch);
   if(isupper(ch) != 0) printf("Is in upper case\n");
}   
return 0;   
 }
```

*Note:* I am using `gcc` to compile on linux (fedora).

Comment: C declares functions implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `gcc` runs in a rather permissive mode.  You can get a warning by adding, for example:

```
 gcc -Wall -c yourfile.c
```

asking for all the main warnings.  (There are more warnings you can asl for: `-Wextra` adds a bunch.)  You might also specify `-std=c99` (and maybe `-pedantic`) in order to get more warnings.

C99 requires functions to be defined or declared before they are used.

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -c warn.c
warn.c:4:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
warn.c: In function ‘main’:
warn.c:4:5: warning: old-style function definition [-Wold-style-definition]
warn.c:9:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘isgraph’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
warn.c:10:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘isupper’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
warn.c:9:8: warning: unused variable ‘g’ [-Wunused-variable]
$
```

That's the output of GCC 4.7.1 (on Mac OS X 10.7.5) with the standard set of compilation options I use — run on your source code stashed in a file `warn.c`.